# Using directives inside controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, using-directives

How can I avoid repeating 10+ using directives inside all of my controllers?

There are about 10+ more using directives in each controller because they reference core framework features that we use in our company. I know you're going to say that logic should be split up so I don't need them all any longer, but that's not an option.

So to be clear, I'm talking about this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
```

Comment: You forgot to explain which 10+ using statements you mean and why you repeat them inside all controllers.

Comment: Maybe you meant [using ***directive***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) instead of [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)?

Comment: NightOwl888, that was indeed what I meant. I'm sorry for the confusion and will change the question.

Answer (score 2):

The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. 
You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the using statement is translated by the compiler.

```
using (Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f)) 
{
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
}
```

Translated by compiler

```
{
  Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
  try
  {
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet; 
  }
  finally
  {
    if (font1 != null)
      ((IDisposable)font1).Dispose();
  }
}
```

So in your case you can add add object initialization in single block and dispose all in the finally block, see below example,

```
{
  Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
 Font font2 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
 Font font3 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
 Font font4 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
 Font font5 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
  try
  {
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet; 
  }
  finally
  {

      ((IDisposable)font1).Dispose();

      ((IDisposable)font2).Dispose();

      ((IDisposable)font3).Dispose();

      ((IDisposable)font4).Dispose();

      ((IDisposable)font5).Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant using directives, not using statements. I have editted my post. Thanks for the effort though.